# Android String Post http

Tags: android, api, http

Tenho um code que gostaria que fizesse um "Post" da string email depois que clicasse no botão,o codigo do post aparentemente está correto  , mas o botão não está funcionando..O logcat não retorna nenhum erro..este é meu codigo :

```
public class PostTeste extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button1;
    private EditText username;
    public String email;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpost);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = username.getText().toString();
              //  String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                //System.out.println(email);
                //System.out.println(password);
                //String cep = mCep.getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Botão funcionou!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

            public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                }

                protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                    try {

                        URL url = new URL("Api URL);

                        JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();




                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", "xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic dGhpYWdvLmNhbWFyZ29AZXZvbHV0aW9uaXQuY29tLmJyOmluaWNpYWwyMDE3");
                        //conn.setRequestProperty("-d", "{}");
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);

                        postDataParams.put("email", "email");
                        //postDataParams.put("password", "password");
                        Log.e("resource", postDataParams.toString());

                        JSONObject resource = new JSONObject();
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                        array.put(postDataParams);
                        resource.put("resource", array);

                        System.out.println(resource.toString());


                        conn.connect();

                        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                        //writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
                        writer.write(resource.toString());

                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        os.close();

                        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                            String line = "";

                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                                sb.append(line);
                                break;
                            }

                            in.close();
                            return sb.toString();
                        } else {
                            return new String("false : " + responseCode);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar o método setOnClickListener, tente criar um método "public void meuClick()" na sua activity e inserida no xml do layout no seu Button a propriedade android:onClick="meuClick".

Isso deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

voce esta chamando o conn.connect() antes de criar o outputStream entao a conexao é feita sem os parametros do post....

tenta colocar este trecho apos o close do output e veja se da certo.